# What are the exact properties of a superconducting coil?

Tags: superconductivity, induction

I've seen plenty of experiments involving a cylinder-shaped superconductor and a floating magnet. I haven't seen many, if any experimentation on the properties of coils.

For example:

Can we measure the current being generated by the opposing fields generated to do the Meissner effect?

If we attach a light bulb or something similar to a superconducting coil, will it lose the current it gains from induction?

Do superconducting coils that are at a temperature less than $T_c$ exhibit any special properties when compared to a regular conducting coil, assuming that both are not infinite loops and are attached to a light bulb or something similar?

Comment: For sure superconductors do not dissipate the current, but a light bulb does (a traditional one even dissipate about 95% of the energy in terms of heating, for about 5% lightning) ! Non-dissipative radiation of a superconductor are outside the visible-light  spectrum. I do not understand the first question about *the opposing fields*, sorry.

Comment: @FraSchelle Well, I guess what i'm asking is whether or not connecting something like a lightbulb would in any way effect the way the Meissner effect operates.